# How to get cookie set by htaccess file on first load

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I need to get cookie value on first load of page, I know cookie can be retrieved on second load.

I need this as I want to redirect based on cookie value set by server htaccss file.

I set cookie this way in htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=fullsite:yes:.example.com]
```

I want to fetch the value in php. I know only this way but this give me cookie value on second load.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['fullsite'])&&$_COOKIE['fullsite']=='yes'){
    echo $_COOKIE['fullsite'];
}
```

Is there a way around to get cookie value from server the first time the server sends cookie please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: See this : https://amitoverflow.com/2019/05/23/how-to-set-cookies-using-rewriterule-in-htaccess-or-server-config-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the cookie and do a full redirect of the URL to make sure cookie is available when PHP code runs:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*fullsite=yes [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,CO=fullsite:yes:.example.com]
```

Comment: Can I get this as `echo $_COOKIE['fullsite'];` in php page the first time it loads.

Comment: Yes you can use `echo $_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"];` to list all the cookies and `echo $_COOKIE['fullsite'];` to list specific cookie.

Comment: Hi, I tried using this approach to solve my other problem but I cant make it work, please see if you can help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245970/htaccess-cannot-set-cookie-and-redirect-from-subdomain-to-main-domain

Comment: Hi can you answer my question, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815539/htaccess-rewriting-rule-rewriting-css-files

Comment: this will generate extra traffic and time-laps to send the redirect back and forth between browser and server.. is there any other way??

Comment: Please post a new question with clear requirements and we will try to answer