# .htaccess rewriting rule rewriting css files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a rewrite rule to make pretty url but its rewriting css, js and other files too.

I want to rewrite

```
http://localhost/example/post/?postid=af1ub4zu4y&title=this-is-the-first-post.html
```

to

```
http://localhost/example/post/af1ub4zu4y/this-is-the-first-post.html
```

I am trying this way

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/(.*\.html) /example/post/?postid=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L,B]
```

also tried like these

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/(.*\.html) /example/post/?postid=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L,B]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/(.*\.html) /example/post/?postid=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L,B]
```

But none of these solution are working for me. Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to rewrite? Provide samples. Also, please confirm whether the htaccess is being loaded; mod-rewrite is enabled etc.,

Comment: @hjpotter92  please see the update, htaccess is loaded and mod-rewrite is enabled

Comment: yes I am getting 404 error

Comment: @anubhava yes in `/example/.htaccess`

Comment: @anubhava yes `/example/post/` is actual directory like `/example/post/index.php`

Comment: @TallboY I'm removing my reply below as you might get confused in the two approaches.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I didn't got confused, I try one solution at a time, anyways thanks for taking time to help

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this rule in `/example/post/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /example/post/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+\.html?)$ ?postid=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L,B,NC]
```

Comment: I have this rule too which is working fine `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]*)$ /example/view/?hash=$1 [QSA,L]
`

Comment: Most probably the OP has put both our solutions to test at the same time! I'll remove my reply.

Comment: I put .htaccess in `/example/post/.htaccess` and still broken css

Comment: `http://localhost/example/post/af1ub4zu4y/this-is-the-first-post.html` is causing broken css.

Comment: `http://localhost/example/post/?postid=af1ub4zu4y&title=this-is-the-first-post.h‌​tml` is working but not getting values from `postid` and `title` and redirects to `http://localhost/example/post/?postid=af1ub4zu4y&title=this-is-the-first-post.h%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btml`

Comment: there is nothing else in `/example/post/.htaccess` and one more rule that I told you in `/example/.htaccess`

Comment: css url causing broken css  `http://localhost/example/post/asset/css/css.css` actual css url `http://localhost/example/asset/css/css.css`

Comment: Still the same broken css, I paste `<base href="/example/" />` after closing `</head>` and before `<body>`

Comment: also tried to put `<base href="/example/" />` after `<head>` but still same broken css

Comment: ya I guess I have to use absolute url or a second level directory in `/post/` to make it work. Anyways thanks for your time and help

Comment: I meant absolute URL to be used in your HTML source for including css/js.