# apache get cookie value from browser in htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing, redirect

> **I want to Get the cookie value from the browser**. Bind it it to a variable or i could use it directly.

Example: In php i can receive the cookies like

```html
if ((isset($_COOKIE['tenant']))) {
    $cookie_name = $_COOKIE['tenant'];
}
```

> Similarly i could do this and want to assign the cookie value to 
>   another variable

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript `document.cookie`. PHP run on the Server side. Javascript and Jquery on Client side (Browser), but only for own Cookies, not for cookies from another sites.

Here is similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252665/i-need-to-get-all-the-cookies-from-the-browser)

There is way how to add Cookies into PHP in JS, but I think it´s not secure.

Comment: Hi Jan Sršeň,  **i want to do this in .htaccess file. ** Please reply if you able to do the same concept which i did in php on  **htaccess apache **

Comment: Maybe try [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html) or StackOverflow old posts for example: [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382160/htaccess-compare-cookie-value-and-redirect-if-evaluation-returns-true-false) or [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245096/how-to-get-cookie-set-by-htaccess-file-on-first-load) or edit Cookie with `RequestHeader edit Cookie "^(.*?)ANY_COOKIE=.*?;(.*)$" $1$2`, but I dont try it